# dataInputStream.read corrupts my binary image data(with content type: Multipart/form) on some servers

Tags: java, http, servlets, multipartform-data, datainputstream

I have an application running that reads images from a client machine and uploads to the server. It uses the dataInputStream's read method to read the bytes from the image data to store in a byte array. In some servers, I notice that the read corrupts the data bytes. Specifically some bytes are incorrectly written to as 3F(?). I see the data correctly on Fiddler but when I print out the binary after the read, I find this corruption occurs( and I see it in the output image binary as well). Can anyone help me witha possible cause/solution

Comment: Identify images that end up "corrupted"; and see if you can reproduce the issue when running the process "locally". In addition, carefully check your code for multi-threading issues; maybe two threads are working on the same data ...

Comment: Show both client and server code that you use for handling the image.

Comment: It looks like all images are corrupted on some web-servers and none on others. I could not find any difference in either the java or the servlet versions in both. I could check my code for multi-threading issues but this does not look likely given that the same software consistently fails on one server and succeeds with another.  I also find it curious that the problematic bytes are always transalated to 0X3F.

Comment: The code is simply a 
dataStreamIn.read(byteArray) where datStreamIn is the inputStream from the servletRequest(httpServletRequest). 
When I see the content of byteArray, the data is corupted and when I see the request on fiddler, the data looks all right.

Comment: Are all the servers using the same OS?

Comment: yes both servers are on windows server 2008 SP2